# Can an application running on a system with a paging memory management system directly access the physical memory?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

In the context of operating systems, does an application have direct access to primary memory?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from a Linux perspective, assuming we're talking about user-level (non-`root`) processes, then no they can't directly access physical memory. Nor should they for security and functionality reasons. The whole point of paging is to abstract away physical memory from applications so that they only think they have the entire physical memory, but behind the scenes, their memory may or not be resident in physical memory (see: page faults, non-contiguous allocation, page replacement policies).

For `root` processes though, there is at least one way I know of: through `/dev/mem`. [This discussion](https://comp.os.linux.development.apps.narkive.com/GP0AQLk6/how-to-map-to-physical-address-by-using-mmap-in-linux#:%7E:text=kernel%20choses%20physical%20addresses%20which%20suit%20itself.&text=this%20mapping.&text=memory%20locations)%20to%20a%20virtual,in%20your%20process%27%20address%20space.) mentions how to `mmap` into `/dev/mem` to get access to specific physical addresses. Use at your own risk though.

Comment: Makes perfect sense!! Thank you for your response :)